# Getting rid of highlighted red stripe on Flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I get rid of the highlighted red tape on Flutter when my content goes beyond the screen? It might be related to debug mode because I don't see it on release but would be nice to still be running my builds on debug mode without it.

EDIT: Here's an example of an implementation that will overflow:

```
class OverflowExample extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State createState() {
    return new OverflowExampleState();
}
}

class OverflowExampleState extends State<OverflowExample> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
        children: [
            new column(
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
            ),
            new column(
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
            ),
            new column(
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
            ),
            new column(
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
            ),
            new column(
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
                new Container(height: 100, width: 200),
            ),
        ]
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That stripe indicates that you've got overflowing content and it will also log errors to the console. It's best to fix these issues by telling Flutter how to handle the overflow.

You can wrap the content in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` (if you're in a `Column` or `Row`) to let Flutter know that it's ok to collapse it. You can also use a `Stack` (which offers options for handling overflow) or a `ListView` (which can scroll). If you're using a `Text` widget, there are several options for how you want overflow to be clipped.

In the example you posted, I think a combination of [`Stack`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [`Positioned`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) will do what you want. You have to set at least one non-null property of the `Positioned` to make it a "positioned" widget, preventing it from determining the dimensions of the `Stack`. You can configure the overflow behavior with the `overflow` property.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverflowExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          child: new Row(
            children: [
              new Column(
                children: [
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('1')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('2')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('3')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('4')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('5')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('6')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('7')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('8')),
                ],
              ),
              new Column(
                children: [
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('1')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('2')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('3')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('4')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('5')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('6')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('7')),
                  new Container(
                    height: 100.0, width: 200.0, child: new Text('8')),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController(
  );
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Material(child: new OverflowExample()),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Yeah my plan was to let it flow on purpose and you can see the rest through gesture detectors.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample, I will show you how to update it to explicitly handle overflow.

Comment: I posted an example

Comment: I updated my answer with your example. `Stack` should do the trick.